# Script for Monero Auto mining

Tags: cpu-mining

need your assistance, please.

Can anyone provide me a script for Mining Monero automatically?
I have some small Internet Cafe an I am planning to put it in my units for additional income.
If you wanna make it confidential kindly PM my [FACEBOOK](https://www.facebook.com/iamsecretjhun)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's the owner of the internet cafe

Answer (score 2):

Look, if you don't own the computers then I don't suggest you mine on them. However if you do own them, then look at using xmr-stack https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak

Answer (score -1):

step 1:

crontab -e

Step 2 then add:

@boot xmr-stack

Step 3:

save & exit

Step 4:

???

Step 5:

Go to jail